# After removing .gitignore, git still giving error?

Tags: git, gitignore

In keeping with the advice from this question:
[Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

We did the following:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
$ git commit -m".gitignore is now working"
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 2 and 24 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
git commit -m".gitignore now works"
git pull

git says:
$ git pull
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
dir/.classpath
```

How do we force git to ignore the .classpath file?

Comment: Yes, fixed it, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You need to commit your changes before pulling:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -m 'Removed dir/.classpath'
git pull
```

Depending on the upstream commits, this could result in a merge conflict. If you get a "modified/deleted" merge conflict in `dir/.classpath`, you will need to remove it again before committing the merge.

```
git rm -r dir/.classpath
git commit # Commit the merge
```

**Edit**: Since you already committed your change, all you need to do is remove the untracked directory before pulling. You may want to **make a backup first** if you need the directory contents.

```
rm -rf dir/.classpath
git pull
```

Comment: @Dov Edited my answer to include removing the directory

Comment: .classpath is not a directory AFAIK, so you might need `rm dir/.classpath` instead of `rm -rf dir/.classpath`